# Payable function 'charges' sender twice value sent in tx after invoking library function

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, library, dapp-debugging

Facing a nasty bug and could really use a pair of fresh eyes.

I have a payable function that is somehow taking twice the value sent to it by the sender, from the sender.  Specifically, it appears to be a call within the payable function to a library method that is incurring the second "charge", if you will.

Here's an excerpt of the parent contract with the payable function, `Remittance.sol`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

import "./Owned.sol";
import "./Data.sol";
import "./Util.sol"; 

contract Remittance is Owned {
    Data.LockBoxes lockBox; 
    Data.LockBoxIndex lockBoxIndex;

    modifier stopInEmergency 
    { 
        if(stopped) throw;
        _; 
    }

    function createLockBox(
        address _receiver,
        bytes32 _password1, 
        bytes32 _password2)   
        stopInEmergency      
        payable
        public 
        returns (bool)
    {
        uint amount = msg.value - ownerFee;         

        // After Data.insert() is invoked, `msg.value` is taken from `msg.sender` again
        if(Data.insert(lockBox, lockBoxIndex, _receiver, msg.sender, amount, _password1, _password2))
        {
            LogLockBoxCreated(_receiver, amount, true);
            deposit(owner, ownerFee);            
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            LogLockBoxCreated(_receiver, amount, false);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Here's a portion of the library code, `Data.sol`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

library Data {

  struct LockBox {
    address creator; 
    uint amount; 
    bytes32 password1; 
    bytes32 password2;
    uint creationTime;
    bool active;
    uint index;        
  }        

  struct LockBoxes { 
      mapping(address => LockBox) boxes; 
  } 

  struct LockBoxIndex { 
      address[] boxIndex; 
  }

  function insert(
      LockBoxes storage s1, 
      LockBoxIndex storage s2,
      address _receiver,
      address _creator,
      uint _amount, 
      bytes32 _password1, 
      bytes32 _password2)
      public
      returns (bool)
  {
      if (s1.boxes[_receiver].active)
           return false;
      s1.boxes[_receiver] = LockBox(_creator, _amount, _password1, _password2, now, true, s2.boxIndex.push(_receiver) - 1);
      return true;
  }  
}
```

And then, in a `truffle test`...

```
remittance.createLockBox.sendTransaction(beneficiary, p1_hash, p2_hash, { from: creator, value: amount })
```

If `amount` in the transaction above is `2 ether`, then the contract will be paid `4 ether` by the sender `creator`!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `deposit` do? If you sent 2 ether then the contract cannot spent more than 2 ethers from your account, if the contract has a balance it can use it whole. Are you testing with testrpc or with a testnet?

Comment: Sorry.  Left out `deposit` for brevity.  It just adds a `uint` value to a `mapping`.  

`pendingWithdrawals[_account] += _deposit;`

I'm uing testrpc. 

"If you sent 2 ether then the contract cannot spent more than 2 ethers from your account"

Right?  And yet, somehow... it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.  I'm not going out of my mind.  The sender really was getting double-dipped, but oops... looks like I'd better update my copy of `testrpc`.

The problem is down to a bug in `ethereumjs-vm`

#### [runCall invoked twice for DELEGATECALL #82](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/issues/82)